# Transceivers connectable with bluetooth hearing aids

Tags: transceiver

I'm a rower in the Netherlands. Rowers are typically coached via transceivers or a megaphone. I am hearing impaired and I will get new hearing aids soon. These will be equipped with bluetooth. My question is: are there transceivers that are connectable with bluetooth devices (such as headphones or in my case hearing aids). Rowers typically use the Motorola TLKR T92, these are also waterproof.

Alternative for transceivers might be a phone connected to my hearing aids, in a water-proof bag and a phonecall. This however does not seem ideal to me.

Thanks in advance,
Tijmen

Comment: If the radio has a phono jack for output, a bluetooth transmitter plugged into it would work.

Answer (score 3):

yes. Yeasu and Icom both make BT audio capable HTs, and others do too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of consumer-grade devices that will convert line/speaker jacks to bluetooth.

As a random example, here's a battery-powered box that sends/receives headphone-level signals to bluetooth and back the other way.

[image]

Downsides, it's another thing to be carried, and another battery to be charged. 
 This example image doesn't look waterproof given the open jacks, but the whole thing could sit in a sealed plastic bag/box and even be secured to the boat in case of rollover.
Your radio would have to have a headphone socket, and probably needs a VOX transmit mode so that you can speak without having to press a button.

Upside - a separate adapter like this could be used on other devices that lack bluetooth.   A home stereo, a television, anything that has an audio out jack.   Even a retro computer could send via this to your bluetooth hearing aid without needing to support bluetooth directly.
If your rowing club/team already provides compatible radios then owning something like this could be a net saving.

---

Side thought  - If your rowing team never transmits, it may be more effective to choose something like this that supports peering to multiple headsets at once.  That way all rowers could listen to one radio in the boat.

Cheap BT earpieces are much more "disposable" than expensive radios per-person.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am mostly in a single. Like I said previously we use a motorola. I dont remember these having audio inputs. Could you recommend a transceive to me? Budget is 300 max.